# How to accomplish this function in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, macros

I need a macro which helps to output the given parameter's name and value. It's something like the following code.

```
#define AA "Hello"
#define BB "World"
#define PRINT(input_param) printf("input_param: %s\n", (input_param))
void main()
{
  PRINT(AA);
  PRINT(BB);
}
```

I'm expecting the result: `AA: Hello\n BB: World\n`

But obviously it's not.
Anybody can correct me? Thanks.

Comment: Why "but obviously it's not" .. what happens when you run this?

Comment: @Levon "input_param: Hello\ninput_param: World\n"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to stringize the macro name with `#`.  This is how `assert()` works as well:

```
#define AA "Hello"
#define BB "World"
#define PRINT(input_param) printf(#input_param ": %s\n", (input_param))
void main()
{
  PRINT(AA);
  PRINT(BB);
}
```

It may be more clear if I wrote it like this:

```
#define PRINT(input_param) printf("%s: %s\n", #input_param, (input_param))
```

Comment: The second one also guards against disasters like `PRINT(bar%foo)`.

Comment: Not that it hurts, but you don't need parens around macro parameters passed as arguments (since they can't contain commas).